# Sizes attribute on srcset-image of unknown width

Tags: html, image, srcset

What values do I put in the sizes attribute of an image using srcset if I don't know the width the image will be displayed at on the page?

In my case, I have an image slider which can display 4 images side by side at once. But it's also possible that the slider has only one image to display. This one image would then take up the horizontal space the 4 images normally use. In case of 4 images, the sizes attribute would be 25vw and in case of 1 image, it would be 100vw. The problem is, I don't know the image count beforehand.

Is there any solution for this case?